# Adding a new subnode with xmlstarlet almost right

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

Can not figure out how to get what I want: adding a new subnode with attributes:

```
cat input.xml | xmlstarlet edit --subnode "//a/b/c" -t elem -n d -v 'e="data3"'
```

gives me

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c>
      <d e="data1"/>
      <d e="data2"/>
      <d>e="data3"</d>
    </c>
  </b>
</a>
```

which is valid xml, as far as I know, but is unacceptable for the app using and defining the file. Is there a way to convince xmlstarlet to produce the output:

```
<d e="data3"/>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `<d a/>` is invalid XML, so NO!

Comment: You're right. Did a quick-n-dirty on the test input. Updated it.

Comment: Rubber ducking helps! Thx, @zx485 .

Answer (score 1):

The answer, thanks to @zx485:

```
cat input.xml | xmlstarlet edit --subnode "//a/b/c" -t elem -n 'd e="data3"'
```